# How can I send the disconnect messages to subscribed clients if one client is disconnected in MQTT?

Tags: node.js, mqtt, broker

I tried client 1 and client 2 program I can able to easily communicate with them. I can easily send the messages and receive the messages with them, but I don't know if one client is disconnected, how can I send the disconnected message to subscribed clients.

client 1:

```
var mqtt=require("mqtt");
var express=require("express");
var app=express();
var options={
    keepalive:100,
    port: 1883,
    clientId:'1',
    clientSession:false,
    host: "http://localhost:8000",
    will:
        {
            topic:'willMag',
            payload:"connection closed abnormallly r",
            qos:1,
            retain:true
        }
};
var client=mqtt.connect("tcp://192.168.43.137:1883",options);
client.on("connect",function()
{
    setInterval(function()
    {
        client.publish("ranjith/princy","hello love you princy",function()
        {
            console.log("message published in client1");
        });
    },2000);
    client.subscribe("bv/nivi");
    client.on("message",function(topic,message)
    {
            console.log("I recieved the topic:"+topic);
            console.log("I recieved the message:"+message);
    });
});
client.on("disconnect",function()
{
    console.log("disconnected client1");
});
app.listen(8000,function()
{
    console.log("server listen at port 8000");
});
```

client 2:

```
var mqtt=require("mqtt");
var express=require("express");
var app=express();
var options={
    keepalive:100,
    port: 1883,
    clientId:'2',
    clientSession:false,
    host: "http://localhost:8086",
    will:
        {
            topic:'willMag',
            payload:"connection closed abnormallly b",
            qos:1,
            retain:true
        }
};
var client=mqtt.connect("tcp://192.168.43.137:1883",options);
client.on("connect",function()
{
    setInterval(function(){
        client.publish("bv/nivi","hello love you nivi",function()
        {
            console.log("message published in client2");
        });
    },2000);

    client.subscribe("ranjith/princy");

        client.on("message",function(topic,message)
        {
            console.log("I recieved the topic:"+topic);
            console.log("I recieved the message:"+message);
        });

});
client.on("disconnect",function()
{
    console.log("disconnected client2");
});
app.listen(8086,function()
{
    console.log("server listen at port 8000");
});
```

Comment: What broker are you using? Do you have access to its log files?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I see you are operating [two Stack Overflow accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8109812/vignesh-ravi), Vignesh. Please do not do that. If you are downvoted sufficiently that one account no longer operates, then you will need to improve the quality of your questions or answers in order to be permitted to post again. Furthermore, it sounds like you need to exercise some patience - adding "I am waiting" on all of your questions in not conducive to getting answers.

Answer (score 0):

It's not totally clear what you are asking here, but:

1. With MQTT you can not know what clients are subscribed to what topics
2. There is no way to know if a message has been delivered to a specific client

You can build a system to determine if a client is probably online. You need to make use of the Last Will and Testament (LWT) feature.

- When your client connects it publishes a retained message to a given topic (e.g. client1/online payload: 1)
- You set the LWT to publish payload 0 to the same topic if the client goes off line due to a crash/network failure
- When you shut the client down cleanly you need to publish a 0 to the topic manually as the LWT will only fire if there is a failure.

Comment: Thankyou for your comment .My question is client1 subscribed  all the topics of client2.if I close the client1 program.I want to send message to client2 program. "client1  is disconnected " because I subscribed client2 topics in client1..This is possible or not.

Comment: I think that the LWT example does just that.